# Decompose covariance matrix into uncorrelated and correlated part

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix

I have an almost diagonal covariance matrix, I would like to decompose it in an uncorrelated and correlated part:

$$
\Sigma = \Sigma_U + \Sigma_C
$$

where all the matrices above are covariance matrices, $\Sigma_U$ is diagonal.
I guess the solution is not unique, but I would like $\Sigma_U$ to be "large", for example with a large determinant or trace.

Has this problem been studied in the past? Is there a closed solution?

Comment: What would such a decomposition help you do?  To gain some insight, notice that when $\Sigma_U=\lambda I$ is a positive multiple of the identity and $\lambda$ is less than the smallest eigenvalue then you obtain a very special solution--and there are plenty more.  They're not terribly revealing or useful as far as I can tell, which is why I wonder about the intended application.

Comment: @whuber, I would like to decompose the correlated part with diagonalization, but I would like to preserve the uncorrelated part in the original basis.

Comment: It's unclear how meaningful or useful that would be, especially because there is such a large manifold of possible solutions.